# How to validate XML input not-null property in Java REST service?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee

I am running the service under TomEE.

The model is very simple:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Card {

    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = false)
    private String cardNumber;

    public Card() {
        //no-op
    }

    public Card(final String s) {
        cardNumber = s;
    }

    public String getCardNumber() {
        return cardNumber;
    }

    public void setCardNumber(String cardNumber) {
        this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
    }
}
```

I followed this example
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs-advanced008.htm

The service is also very simple like:

```
@Consumes(APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(APPLICATION_XML)
public class MyService {
    @POST 
    @Path("status")
    public String queryStatus(Card card) {
        // do something 
    }
}
```

If my input is wrongly formatted, it will have a proper exception. But it doesn't seem to be able to validate empty card number or null.

For example, when I have

```
"<card></card>"
```

or

```
"<card><cardNumber> </cardNumber></card>"
```

(with an empty string), the service still goes through, with the "cardNumber" property being null or empty.

Well, I could do something in the setter to throw out an exception. But I was hoping JavaEE automatically handle this kind of this if I put the annotation on the property.

So what am I missing here?
Thank you for any tips!

Comment: package javax.validation.constraints contains bean validation annotations. One of the annotations is javax.pattern.constraints.Pattern that helps constrain the value of a field based on the user defined regex. [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html) You may want to test if that helps. Note that I have not tested this myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Bean Validation (http://beanvalidation.org/) Java EE offers a standard way to validate objects. It is also integrated with JAX RS.

So you can use annotations like `@NotNull` in your Card class. In your Service just say that you want a `@Valid` Card.

An example can be found here: https://jaxenter.com/integrating-bean-validation-with-jax-rs-2-106887.html

Comment: sigh...I really think you gave me a right answer and it is still not firing the validation. I added the dependencies from this page http://samaxes.com/2013/01/beanvalidation-with-jaxrs-in-javaee6/, I added the ValidateRequest header to my service, and Valid to the input, as well as NotNull  Size(min = 4) to the property. Not working at all. In fact, I put a breakpoint in the Card constructor or the setter, not hit. Who is creating this object? my request can go directly into the service method

Comment: The article from your link explains, that automatic validation comes with jax-rs 2. if you are using jax-rs 1, then you need to add the dependencies. In the article they are marked as "provided", which is not true for TomEE, you need to package them into your war. According to the documentation, you also need an initializer: http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.13.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#d4e113

Comment: ah, I realize that TomEE is actually EE 6.0 and we are using CXF, so I can't use what those examples are using (Resteasy). Do you have any tips how to use CXF for bean validation in TomEE? I am doing my own research at this moment...

Comment: I don't have any experiences with resteasy, but from the documentation it sounded like its compatible with other frameworks/implemetations of jax-rs

Comment: This topic was also discussed on the TomEE mailing list: http://tomee-openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/JAX-RS-Bean-Validation-td4667501.html

Comment: sigh...I gave up. I am going to XSD validation. this Java eco-system is very confusing.  CXF, Jersey, Spring, EJB, Glassfish, etc., every combo of different implementation will require different configuration and style. Everything I found online seems to assume people know exactly what those config are, and none of those works in my local environment... I was simply trying to do bean validation without writing XSD. nothing works in this tomEE setting, I don't know what I am missing, a lot of attempts build but throw exceptions in the runtime. It's super frustrating to work with Java :(

Comment: Yeah it might be confusing if everything is mixed together. You have to understand the differences: JavaEE is a standard with specifications (e.g. JAX-RS)... then there are many implementations of these specifications (e.g. CXF, jersey). An application server combines implementations for all the specs into one single product (TomEE, Glassfish). The problem with TomEE here is that it does not support the newest version of JavaEE. Spring is an "alternative" to JavaEE, supporting some specs, but with their own philosophy. You have to know where you are and then you know what to search for :)